# How do I convert incorrect characters an Excel file back to normal?

Tags: excel, encoding, character-encoding

I cannot find a solution to this problem. I have thousands of rows of data and all the French and German accents are messed up in those words, example:

```
ÌÉ‰Û¼Ìã‰ÛÁ
```

Is there a way to change this back to another format, or is it too late? I cannot change the data source by the way, that isn't an option. I'm stuck with this sheet. If I cannot change them back, can I highlight them in some way?

Comment: It looks like unicode characters have been reverted to an estimated ASCII character equivalent. If you have enough entries to develop a cypher key where a search and replace can look for a character and replace it with the correct one then this process could be automated but I know of no such 'pre-built' function. Perhaps someone has previously had an identical situation to yours and already has a solution but you'll have to research that yourself or put in the time to work out what has been replaced with what so that the process can be reversed.